# passing variable to view, kohana 3.3 not working, Undefined variable:

Tags: variables, kohana

i have a stupid question... why if i pass e variable to view the browser return me 
 Undefined variable: ? I just clone my first method (for the ads, the same procedure). But with ads work, and with category not work, this is so stupid, why?
i show my little application

my controller:

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

class Controller_Ads extends Controller_Template {

    public $template = 'template';

    // function indes Ads
    public function action_index()
    {
        $ads = ORM::factory('ads')->find_all(); // load all object inside ads table

        $view = new View('ads/index');  // load the view/ads/index.php
        $view->set('ads', $ads);        // set 'ads' object to view

        $this->template->set('content', $view);
    }

    // view single ads
    public function action_single()
    {
        $id = $this->request->param('id');
        $record = ORM::factory('ads')
        ->where('id_ads', '=', $id)
        ->find();

        $view = new View('ads/single');
        $view->set('ads', $record);         

        $this->template->set('content', $view);
    }

    public function action_category()
    {
        $category = ORM::factory('category')->find_all(); 

        $view = new View('ads/index');  
        $view->set('category', $category);      

        $this->template->set('content', $view);
    }

} // End Ads
```

my interest view (ads/index.php)

```
    <?php foreach ($ads as $obj) : ?>
        <h3><?php echo HTML::anchor('/ads/single/'.$obj->id_ads, $obj->title_ads); ?></h3>
        <p><?php echo $obj->description_ads; ?></p>
        <p>Autore: <?php echo $obj->author_ads; ?> || creato il <?php echo $obj->date_ads; ?> || categoria: <?php echo HTML::anchor('#', $obj->category->category_name); ?></p>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php foreach ($category as $obj) : ?>
    <?php echo $obj->id; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

the error in the browser

```
ErrorException [ Notice ]: Undefined variable: category
```

why only for category ?? and not for ads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only one of action functions gets run, 
This means in `action_index()` the `$ads` variable is being set but not `$category`.
And in `action_category()` the $category variable is being set but not `$ads`.

If you only expect to use of those variables, you should make another ads/category.php view and use that in the `action_category()` function, and remove the references to `$ads` in that view.

Also it seem that you are expecting the `action_category()` function to be running, based on the error you are seeing, it is actually running `action_index()`. Check your routes to find out why.